# Rails output a hash to html of x * y rows

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3, html-table

I have a hash of images that i'd like to output via a html table.

It's a basic task that I've done in PHP but I'd like to see what magical stuff ruby can do to achieve it easily.

I've looked at helpers and tutorials and they're all very complicated.

Here's how I am currently printing the images.. How would I convert it to output to something like a 4 x n table?

```
    <% @photos.each do |photo| %>

    <%= image_tag photo["images"][4]["source"] %><br/>

    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [`each_slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) method, which lets you grab your array in groups of a given size.  You should be able to do something like

```
<table>
<% @photos.each_slice(4) do |group| %>
      <tr>
      <%group.each do |photo|%>
           <td>
           <%= image_tag photo["images"][4]["source"] %>
           <td>
      <% end %>
      </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [in_groups_of](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Array/Grouping.html#M000833) might help you out:

```
<table>
<% @photos.in_groups_of(4, false) do |photos| %>
    <tr>
    <% photos.each do |photo| %>
        <td><%= image_tag photo["images"][4]["source"] %></td>
    <% end %>
    </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

By passing `false` as the second argument, the last row might be incomplete. If you want to show a blank image instead, you can pass an empty photo object (assuming its URI points to the blank image your website is using) or simply the direct URI, if the photos array is only an array of URIs.

Comment: Hi, I tried using in_groups_of before but it's throws undefined method or something.. Thanks.